# Argument of type 'EventTypes' is not assignable to parameter of type string

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to add types to the below function,

```
  clickEvent(event:Event) {
    this.event = event
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<a [href]="href" [target]="target" (click)="clickEvent('text')"></a>
```

**Types**

```
export interface EventTypes {
  click?: string;
  load?: string;
  link?: string;
}
```

When I assign the types to `clickEvent`, I'm getting this error on `event`

> [ts] Argument of type 'EventTypes' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'string'. [2345]

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Why did you change your question? Now the answer doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your tagLink method in your service. Method definitions looks like it only accepts string, but you are passing a variable of type **`EventTypes`**

```
this.informationTaggingService.tagLink('onclick', this.text, z_eventType, 
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: So Wat is the Fix >